# jQuery: При нажатии на фото, должен показать индекс

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал такой код:

```
<div class="details">
<img src="" id="foto1">
<img src="" id="foto2">
<img src="" id="foto3">
<img src="" id="foto4">
</div>

$('.details').on('click', function(){alert($(this).index())})
```

Как правильно делать так, чтобы при нажатии на первое фото (id="foto1") вышел индекс 0, на второе фото (id="foto2") индекс 1 и т.д. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно добавить обработчик клика на саму картинку. Для этого можно использовать например делегирование:

```js
$('.details').on('click','img', function(){alert($(this).index())})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="details">
<img src="#" id="foto1">
<img src="#" id="foto2">
<img src="#" id="foto3">
<img src="#" id="foto4">
</div>
```